# Data comparison between two environments -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regression, toad

To check new code functionality (Regression testing) , data copy needed of around 200 tables : Transactional  based on date range , Config tables and ref tables.

Is there an efficient way of comparing the data between two environments ?This is a simple comparison of counts but very time consuming if done manually.
Select Date , count(*) from Table_A where Date = test_date
And
Select count(*) from Ref_table

Comment: No, there is no simple way. You must make at least two passes on every table as you outer join them one way to find additional rows + modified rows, and then the other way to find deleted rows. You can use a full join to do this with one SQL, but under the covers it breaks it up into two passes like I just explained. Also, COUNT(*) doesn't compare data, just counts. It won't tell you if the column values are different or what row identities are added/missing. At best it's a sanity check, which of course could be useful given your requirement.

Comment: Of course, there's no reason to do anything "manually". Write a PL/SQL script that goes through the tables and assembles the SQL for the comparison dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DB link and use it in PL/SQL block to check the count by putting table name as hardcoded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).